# вывести информацию с массива, используя переменную в переменной

Tags: php, массивы

Просто как простой пример. Есть несколько вариантов имен ключей:

```
$main = array();
$main['name']['firstname'] = 'Vasya';
$main['name']['lastname'] = 'Pupkin';
$main['adress'] = '';
$main['city'] = 'Moscow';
```

Ключ Фамилии закидываю в переменную

```
$key_lastname = "['name']['lastname']";
```

В нужном мне случае вывести информацию через переменную переменных

```
$test = ${'main'.$key_lastname};

echo $test;
```

выводит ничего ...

Не смог найти информации как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать можно и не так сложно. Только ключи массива нужно записывать немного другим образом.

```php
$keys = "name.lastname";

$result = array_reduce(explode('.', $keys), function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry[$item];
}, $main);

echo $result;
```

Comment: вы просто волшебник, спасибо!